# Prevent key press from going to element focused by keyboard event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, keyboard-events

I have an `.add-color` div that can be clicked to create an contenteditable span and then focus on the latter.

But for accessibility sake, I've also set it up so that a keyboard event handler triggers the same event when the user presses <enter> or <space> while focused on the `.add-color` div. Unfortunately when the latter happens, the <enter> or <space> character is passed to the newly focused span, which I do not want.

Is there any way to prevent that character from being passed to the contenteditable span? Might there be some way to clear the keyboard input buffer (or swallow the key press) in my `dom.KeyActivate` method?

In my DOM utilties:

```
dom.KeyActivate = function(fcn) {
  return function(evt) {
    if(evt.key !== 'Enter' && evt.key !== " ") {
      return;
    }
    fcn(evt);
  }
};
```

And in the widget definition:

```
_create: function() {
  const $rangeBar = self.element.find('.rangeBar');
  self._on({
    "click .add-color": () => self._AddColor($rangeBar),
    "keypress .add-color": dom.KeyActivate( 
      () => self._AddColor($rangeBar)
    ),
  })
},

_AddColor: function($parent) {
    $(`<span contenteditable="true" type="number" name="ranges[]">?</span>`)
      .appendTo($parent).focus();

},
```

In case it makes any difference, I'm doing my development on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution: just delay the `focus()` until after the call stack is clear using `setTimeout`:

```
_AddColor: function($parent) {
  const $numSpan = $(`<span contenteditable="true" type="number" name="ranges[]">?</span>`)
    .appendTo($parent);
  setTimeout( ()=> {$numSpan.focus()}, 0 );
}
```